# Can I use Swift's 'Any' in a Realm property?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Using `Any` as type raises an exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   'Property 'value' is declared as 'Swift._NSContiguousString', which is
>   not a supported RLMObject property type. All properties must be
>   primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber, RLMArray,
>   RLMLinkingObjects, or subclasses of RLMObject. See
>   https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html for more
>   information.'

Comment: As stated in your error message: All properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber, RLMArray, RLMLinkingObjects, or subclasses of RLMObject.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. As both the error and the [official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#supported-types) states, only the following types are allowed to be stored as Realm properties:

- Bool
- Int
- Int8
- Int16
- Int32
- Int64
- Double
- Float
- String
- Date
- Data

Comment: How to get around this? I need to represent more than one type

Comment: Without knowing what exactly is it you are trying to achieve, it's quite hard to give any workarounds. In general, you shouldn't have properties of type `Any` even in normal Swift classes... If you have to use `Any` for anything permanent, you are most probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I need to represent more than one type.

Comment: That's not an exact use case. Why do you think you need to do that? Without knowing the exact scenario, I cannot tell you what's the best workaround. If for instance you have a network response, where a certain key can represent 2 types, you can simply create a property with both types and make them optional.

Comment: As I've said several times, without knowing your exact use case no one will be able to give you the best workaround possible.

Comment: In 20 years of coding I've never come across a situation where "Any" can't be replaced with Fixed types if the design is fixed. If you don't know whats going in your schema, its because you *havent finished the design yet*

Answer (score 0):

Any not supported by Realm. You can't use "Any" property type. [Realm Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/). Realm supports variety types of properties as follows:

- Int, Int8, Int16, Int32, and Int64
- Boolean
- Float
- String
- NSDate
- NSData
- Class extends Object => Used for One-to-one
  relations
- List => Used for one-to-many relations